# how to enable add button after validation of text box?

Tags: jquery, html

I am creating text box dynamically using "Add another url".
I put the url counter for 5 urls only.

In this i am validating url using jquery then submit final urls.

But how to disable "add another url" button if first url is not correct. so that i can not create second or third text box.

If url is correct then button is enabled.

Code as follows

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/F7fmL/)

```
var current= 1;

$(document).ready(function() {

$("#addURL").click(function() {
    if(current<5)
    {
        current++;
        $newPerson= $("#userTemplate").clone(true);
        $newPerson.children("p").children("label").each(function(i) {
            var $currentElem= $(this);
            $currentElem.attr("for",$currentElem.attr("for")+current);
        });
        $newPerson.children("p").children("input").each(function(i) {
            var $currentElem= $(this);
            $currentElem.attr("name",$currentElem.attr("name")+current);
            $currentElem.attr("id",$currentElem.attr("id")+current);
        });



        $newPerson.appendTo("#mainField");
        $newPerson.removeClass("hideElement");

        //add validation
        $("#url0"+current).rules("add", { required:true,url:true });
        if(current == 5)
            $("#addURL").hide();
    }       
});


$("#demoForm").validate({
    rules: {
        url1: {
            required: true,
            url: true


        }
    },

    submitHandler: function(form) {
    if($("#demoform").valid()) {
        alert("hello");
        }

    }
});


console.log('r');
});
</script>

<style>
.hideElement {display:none;}
</style>

</head>

<body>



<form name="demoForm" id="demoForm" method="post" action="">
<fieldset id="mainField">
<div id="userTemplate" class="hideElement">
<p>
    <label for="url0">Enter a valid URL</label> <em>* </em><input id="url0" name="url0" size="100" />

</p>
</div>
<div>
    <p>
        <label for="url1">Enter a valid URL</label>  
        <em>* </em><input id="url1" name="url1" size="100" />
    </p>
</div>
</fieldset>

<p>
<input type="button" id="addURL" value="Add Another URL">
</p>

<input type="submit" value="Save">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my take on this.

I, among other things fixed your illegal ID on second newPerson and on. I also got rid of current as a counter, I count visible divs instead

One strange finding is that I can enter an invalid URL, see the Add another grey out, then I can add another, mess with the PREVIOUS and get a situation where I can add another but one of the ones I added is not valid.

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/axkXW/)

```
$(function () {
    $("#addURL").click(function () {
        var current = $("#mainField").children("div:visible").length;
        var $prev = $("#mainField div:visible").find("input");
        var isValid=$prev.eq(current-1).valid();        
        console.log($prev.attr("id"),isValid);
        $("#addURL").prop("disabled",!isValid);
        if (!isValid || current >= 5) {
            $("#addURL").prop("disabled",true);
            return false;
        }
        $newPerson = $("#userTemplate").clone(true);
        $newPerson.attr("id","person"+current);
        $newPerson.children("p").children("label").each(function (i) {
          var $currentElem = $(this);
          $currentElem.attr("for", $currentElem.attr("for") + current);
        });
        $newPerson.children("p").children("input").each(function (i) {
          var $currentElem = $(this);
          $currentElem.attr("name", $currentElem.attr("name") + current);
          $currentElem.attr("id", $currentElem.attr("id") + current);
        });

        //Technically, you could update the attributes with one loop...
        //
        //      $newPerson.children("p").children("label,input").each...
        //
        //  ...but you end up assigning "NaN" names and ids to the labels and other such wackiness.

        $newPerson.appendTo("#mainField");
        $newPerson.removeClass("hideElement");

        //add validation
        $("#url0" + current).rules("add", {
          required: true,
                url: true
        });
    });


    $("#demoForm").validate({
        rules: {
            url1: {
                required: true,
                url: true
            }
        },
        success: function() {
          $("#addURL").prop("disabled",false);  
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            if ($("#demoform").valid()) {
                alert("hello");
            } else {
                $('#addURL').prop('disabled', true);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Dear mplunghan!! In php how can we access these text data. what will be $_POST[''] data?

Comment: Instead of alert you need to do a `$.post("yourserverprocess.php",$("#demoform").serialize(),function(data){alert(data)})`

Answer (score 2):

```
if($(this).valid()) {
    $('#addURL').css('disabled', false);
    }
    else{
        $('#addURL').css('disabled', true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check This **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/F7fmL/5/)**

In order to disable a button based on validation:

```
 $(document).on('focusout','input[id^="url"]', function() {
         var isValid = $("#demoForm").valid();
         var inputVal = $(this).val();

         if(inputVal != "" &&  isValid == false)
         {
             $("#addURL").attr("disabled", true);
         }
         else
         {
             $("#addURL").attr("disabled", false);
         }
    });
```

Comment: in "FIDDLE" without writing anything, if we click on button then also it is creating new text box. Initially it should be disble, if url is wrong or not entered